# $.getJson() response limit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using $.getJson() function to return an array located in a separate json file and store it into a local array var. The problem I'm having is that I'm only getting back 20 of the total 25 items from the json. Does $.getJson have a limit to the number of returned items?

this is how i'm using the code:

Javascript:

```
$.getJSON('data/gridData1.json',function(json){
                console.log("Json length is: " + json.length);
                var grid = json;
                filterGrid(grid, ele);
            });
```

Json:

```
[
 {"assignment":"Tom" , "cell":["Tom", "2013-10-06", "Client 3", "Activity", "Scheduled" ]}
,{"assignment":"Tom" , "cell":["Tom", "2007-10-06", "Client 2", "Alert" , "Work In Progress" ]}
,{"assignment":"Tom" , "cell":["Tom", "2013-10-06", "Client 3", "Activity", "In Progress" ]}
,{"assignment":"Tom" , "cell":["Tom", "2007-10-06", "Client 1", "Lead" , "Qualified" ]}
,{"assignment":"Tom" , "cell":["Tom", "2007-10-06", "Client 2", "Alert" , "Open" ]}
,{"assignment":"Jenny" , "cell":["Jenny" , "2007-10-06", "Client 1", "Notification" , "New" ]}
,{"assignment":"Jenny" , "cell":["Jenny" , "2007-10-06", "Client 3", "Lead" , "Qualified" ]}
,{"assignment":"Jenny" , "cell":["Jenny" , "2007-10-05", "Client 2", "Lead" , "Unqualified" ]}
,{"assignment":"Jenny" , "cell":["Jenny" , "2007-10-05", "Client 1", "Activity"  , "In Progress" ]}
,{"assignment":"Jenny" , "cell":["Jenny" , "2007-10-05", "Client 3", "Lead" , "Qualified" ]}
,{"assignment":"Jenny" , "cell":["Jenny" , "2007-10-04", "Client 3", "Lead" , "Unqualified" ]}
,{"assignment":"Katie" , "cell":["Katie", "2007-10-06", "Client 2", "Activity" , "Draft" ]}
,{"assignment":"Katie" , "cell":["Katie", "2007-10-06", "Client 1", "Activity" , "Draft" ]}
,{"assignment":"Katie" , "cell":["Katie", "2007-10-06", "Client 2", "Activity" , "In Progress" ]}
,{"assignment":"Brad" , "cell":["Brad" , "2007-10-06", "Client 1", "Activity" , "Scheduled" ]}
,{"assignment":"Brad" , "cell":["Brad" , "2007-10-06", "Client 3", "Activity" , "Scheduled" ]}
,{"assignment":"Brad" , "cell":["Brad" , "2007-10-05", "Client 2", "Activity" , "In Progress" ]}
,{"assignment":"Brad" , "cell":["Brad" , "2007-10-05", "Client 1", "Alert"  , "Work In Progress" ]}
,{"assignment":"Brad" , "cell":["Brad" , "2007-10-05", "Client 3", "Alert" , "Open" ]}
,{"assignment":"Brad" , "cell":["Brad" , "2007-10-04", "Client 3", "Notification" , "New" ]}
,{"assignment":"Hank" , "cell":["Hank", "2013-10-06", "Client 3", "Lead", "Unqualified" ]}
,{"assignment":"Hank" , "cell":["Hank", "2007-10-06", "Client 2", "Alert" , "Work In Progress" ]}
,{"assignment":"Hank" , "cell":["Hank", "2007-10-06", "Client 1", "Lead" , "Qualified" ]}
,{"assignment":"Hank" , "cell":["Hank", "2007-10-06", "Client 2", "Alert" , "Open" ]}
,{"assignment":"Mike" , "cell":["Mike" , "2007-10-04", "Client 3", "Notification" , "New" ]}
]
```

The console log shows the result: 20. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: `.getjson()` is just a wrapper around `.ajax()` and assumes a JSON response from the server. It has no built-in limits. if you're only getting 20 elements, then the server's only sending 20 elements.

Comment: yes, I just ran it again and now it's displaying everything. I have no clue why it wasn't working in the first place, because I didn't make any changes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no set limit on the size of a JSON response, any more than there is
on an HTML or XML response. You can have very large JSON responses with no
problem.
GET vs. POST would have nothing to do with this. Those are only different in
the way the request is sent to the server; the response format for GET and
POST is identical.

Though in case of request to the server with large amount of data ,Post is preferred, but the response from the server has no limit in both GET and POST